# Connecting to MySQL server via kubernetes pod using Intellij

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, kubernetes, amazon-rds

We have a MySQL server that is running on AWS using AWS RDS service and some Kubernetes pods which run some services that connect to this MySQL instance.

I have been using Intellij Idea (2020.1) to connect to these MySQL servers for quite some time. However, recently we have changed the policy to connect to these instances, and now it's only possible to connect to the MySQL servers from the Kubernetes pods. Hence, I now need to login to these pods and then query MySQL using the command-line MySQL-client.

Is there any way I can still use Intellij to connect to these MySQL instances than having to log in to the pods using something like SSH tunnelling or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting up an SSH tunnel is recently straight forwards, but the setup depends on your VPC and EC2 configuration. There are a lot of how-tos on the net, e.g.: https://medium.com/@michalisantoniou6/connect-to-an-aws-rds-using-an-ssh-tunnel-22f3bd597924

Comment: I can't directly SSH to the RDS instance since the policies only allow connecting via the kubernetes nodes. Is there a way I can SSH to the kubernetes pod? I generally use `kubectl` to login to the k8s pod.

Comment: In that case you would first have to ssh into one of your K8s worker nodes, from there ssh into a ssh provisioned Pod/Container and from there to RDS.

Comment: I just verified, SSH'ing into the k8s pod has not been enabled either. I can only login to the pod using `kubectl`.